# _DecodeError('Unexpected end-group tag.') when running import_pb_to_tensorboard.py

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am trying out ways to deploy tensorflow model on android/iOS devices. So I did: 
        1) use tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder to get model in .pb file
        2) use tf.saved_model.loader.load() to verify that I can restore the model

However, when I want to do further inspection of the model using import_pb_to_tensorboard.py following suggestions at 
        1) https://medium.com/@daj/how-to-inspect-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-5fd2ee79ced0
        2) https://hackernoon.com/running-a-tensorflow-model-on-ios-and-android-ce89446c8143

I got this error:

```
    File "/Users/rjtang/_hack/env.tensorflow_src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1083, in MergeFromString
if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
    .....
    File "/Users/rjtang/_hack/env.tensorflow_src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 612, in DecodeRepeatedField
if value.add()._InternalParse(buffer, pos, new_pos) != new_pos:
    ....
    File "/Users/rjtang/_hack/env.tensorflow_src/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 746, in DecodeMap
raise _DecodeError('Unexpected end-group tag.')
```

The code and the generated .pb files are here:

- https://github.com/rjt10/hear_it/blob/master/urban_sound/saved_model.pb
  https://github.com/rjt10/hear_it/blob/master/urban_sound/savedmodel_save.py
  https://github.com/rjt10/hear_it/blob/master/urban_sound/savedmodel_load.py

The version of tensorflow that I use is built from source "HEAD detached at v1.4.1"

Answer (score 2):

Well, I understand what's happening now. Tensorflow has at least 3 ways to save and load a model. The graph will be serialized as one of the following 3 protobuf objects:

1. GraphDef
2. MetaGraphDef
3. SavedModel

You just need to deserialize it properly, such as https://github.com/rjt10/hear_it/blob/master/urban_sound/model_check.py

For Android, TensorFlowInferenceInterface() expects a GraphDef, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e2be6d4c4fc9f1b7f6040b51b23190c14202e797/tensorflow/contrib/android/java/org/tensorflow/contrib/android/TensorFlowInferenceInterface.java#L541

That explains why.